# Prove or Disprove: $AA^T=D_1\land A^TA=D_2\implies {\forall i\not=j, a_{ij}=0}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given any matrix $A\in\mathbb C^{m\times n}$ or $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$, and $D_1,D_2$ are diagonal matrices, is it possible to prove/disprove that:

1. $AA^T=D_1\land A^TA=D_2\implies {\forall i\not=j, a_{ij}=0}$
2. Change $A^T$ to $A^*$ of the above.

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Did you try a few examples?

Comment: What do you mean by $A^\ast$ when $F$ is a general field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin, you may consider a matrix of size $2$. Let $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}$. Then

\begin{aligned}
AA^T&=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}\pmatrix{a&c\\ b&d}
=\pmatrix{a^2+b^2&ac+bd\\ ac+bd&c^2+d^2},\\
A^TA&=\pmatrix{a&c\\ b&d}\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}
=\pmatrix{a^2+c^2&ab+cd\\ ab+cd&b^2+d^2}.
\end{aligned}
It follows that
\begin{aligned}
AA^T \text{ is diagonal } &\Leftrightarrow ac+bd=0,\\
A^TA \text{ is diagonal } &\Leftrightarrow ab+cd=0,\\
A \text{ is diagonal } &\Leftrightarrow b=c=0.
\end{aligned}
Therefore, if you want to prove the statement in question, you need to prove that
$$ac+bd=0=ab+cd\ \text{ implies that }\ b=c=0.$$
If you want to disprove the statement instead, you need to find some $a,b,c,d\in F$ such that
$$ac+bd=0=ab+cd\ \text{ but }\ (b,c)\ne(0,0).$$

Answer (score 0):

You'll find plenty of counter-examples in orthogonal matrices.
For example (here the rows aren't orthonormal, but it doesn't matter):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 \\ 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ -2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 0 \\ 0 & 5
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

etc.